# Who was the Yoga Guru of Swami Vivekananda?

Tags: history, yoga, guru, vivekananda

I know that Swami Vivekananda's Mantra Guru was Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa. But this is about his Yoga Guru (if he had any).

In Hinduism the importance Guru is paramount.

Swami Vivekananda himself explains the importance of Guru in spiritual practice as follows:

> Every soul is destined to be perfect, and every being, in the end,
> will attain the state of perfection. Whatever we are now is the result
> of our acts and thoughts in the past; and whatever we shall be in the
> future will be the result of what we think and do now. But this, the
> shaping of our own destinies, does not preclude our receiving help
> from outside; nay, in the vast majority of cases such help is
> absolutely necessary. When it comes, the higher powers and
> possibilities of the soul are quickened, spiritual life is awakened,
> growth is animated, and man becomes holy and perfect in the end.
>
> This quickening impulse cannot be derived from books. The soul can
> only receive impulses from another soul, and from nothing else. We may
> study books all our lives, we may become very intellectual, but in the
> end we find that we have not developed at all spiritually. It is not
> true that a high order of intellectual development always goes hand in
> hand with a proportionate development of the spiritual side in Man. In
> studying books we are sometimes deluded into thinking that thereby we
> are being spiritually helped; but if we analyse the effect of the
> study of books on ourselves, we shall find that at the utmost it is
> only our intellect that derives profit from such studies, and not our
> inner spirit. This inadequacy of books to quicken spiritual growth is
> the reason why, although almost every one of us can speak most
> wonderfully on spiritual matters, when it comes to action and the
> living of a truly spiritual life, we find ourselves so awfully
> deficient. To quicken the spirit, the impulse must come from another
> soul.
>
> The person from whose soul such impulse comes is called the Guru — the
> teacher; and the person to whose soul the impulse is conveyed is
> called the Shishya — the student. To convey such an impulse to any
> soul, in the first place, the soul from which it proceeds must possess
> the power of transmitting it, as it were, to another; and in the
> second place, the soul to which it is transmitted must be fit to
> receive it. The seed must be a living seed, and the field must be
> ready ploughed; and when both these conditions are fulfilled, a
> wonderful growth of genuine religion takes place. "The true preacher
> of religion has to be of wonderful capabilities, and clever shall his
> hearer be" — आश्चर्यो वक्ता कुशलोऽस्य लब्धा ;
>
> [**Source**](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_3/Bhakti-Yoga/The_Need_of_Guru)

Yoga, being one the foremost spiritual practices, also needs to be learnt directly from a Guru. And, Swami Vivekananda was known to be an adept Yogi.

- So, from whom did Swami Vivekananda learn Yoga? Who were his Yoga Gurus (if any)?

Comment: what do you mean by Yoga ? Raja/Jnana/Karma/Hatha ? the beauty of mantra and any type of yoga is that it automatically obtain knowledge of other yogas if you follow that one perfectly.

Comment: Yoga here means a combination of Hatha and Raja. I am not talking about Jyana, Karma etc. Just like Lahiri Mahasaya's Yoga Guru was Mahavatar Babaji, Yukteswar's Yoga Guru was Lahiri Mahasya, I am here seeking similar information about Vivekananda @ram

Comment: Vivekananda wanted to learn Hatha yoga from Pavhari Baba (who subsisted only on air), but Ramakrishna forbade him in a dream.

Comment: He learned Raja from Ramakrishna. He never learned Hatha.